# How do I refactor this code by using any type of loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

everyone. I am new to the programming and I can't figure out how to refactor this code using loops, so the panels would be switching exactly like in the slider by pressing right arrow key(I commented out my attempt).

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    if (panels[0].classList.contains("active")) {
      panels[0].classList.remove("active");
      panels[1].classList.add("active");
    } else if (panels[1].classList.contains("active")) {
      panels[1].classList.remove("active");
      panels[2].classList.add("active");
    } else if (panels[2].classList.contains("active")) {
      panels[2].classList.remove("active");
      panels[3].classList.add("active");
    } else if (panels[3].classList.contains("active")) {
      panels[3].classList.remove("active");
      panels[4].classList.add("active");
    } else if (panels[4].classList.contains("active")) {
      panels[4].classList.remove("active");
      panels[0].classList.add("active");
    }
    //     for (let i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    //       if (panels[i].classList.contains("active")) {
    //         panels[i].classList.remove("active");
    //         panels[++i].classList.add("active");
    //       }
    //       if (i > panels.length - 1) {
    //         panels[panels.length - 1].classList.remove("active");
    //         panels[0].classList.add("active");
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let j = (i + 1) % 5;
      if (panels[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        panels[i].classList.remove("active");
        panels[j].classList.add("active");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This code uses modulo, so that in the last loop, the second number eqauls to

```
5%5 = 0
```